# How to insert unique woo commerce product in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to import products from `xml` file to woo commerce. This system will insert and update product details every day. When I was inserted products all data imported. But when I was tried to update products are duplicated. I had tried use `post_meta`. But I can not detect some products and duplicated. Please help me how I can insert products without duplicates...
This is my product insert code.

```
$post = array(
                'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
                'post_content' => (string)$product->ExtDesc,
                'post_status' => "publish",
                'post_title' => (string)$product->ItemDesc,
                'post_type' => "product",
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post, $wp_error);
```

I had created a custom unique `column('item_code')` in `wp_posts` table. But I can not insert it with `wp_insert_post` function. Please help me!

Comment: 1. Add the custom unique `item_code` as product meta using the `_sku` key 2. Before inserting the post run a sql select query using `$wpdb` and check if the custom unique `item_code` exists in the `_sku` key for any product, if it does, update the post else create a new one.

Comment: It is not good idea! I have more 20k products to insert. If I will do like what you say than I must run select 20k times. It is not productive.

Comment: You can run 1 select and fetch all the post_id,item_code in an array, then when looping over the products you can use `in_array` to check if the item_code you are about insert exists in the array, if it does update else insert. If you come up something productive please let me know.

Comment: You right. But how many memory use all 20k data? Do you think about this?